# No warnings in VScode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am using VScode for django web devlopment(beginner) ,as you can see ,I have not imported 'include'function but have used it in the path function...I should get a warning at least but there is none..and there is no app declared as calc and it is also not showing any warnings.
[image]

Comment: Also try installing some linter of your choice. Make sure to install it in your virtualenv if you are using one. Linters help me write better code.

Answer (score 1):

Your print screen says that the file hasn't been saved yet, as it is marked as `unsaved`, perhaps that's the issue.

Try to save and see if any warning appears.

Comment: related: [Why don't other programs see the changes I made to a file in VS Code until I save those changes?](/q/76984829/11107541)

Answer (score 0):

Please install the language extension for VSCode for it to support features in the language you are working. Here you seem to be using DJango. For that install  the python extension and preferably the Django extension and verify

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

This will provide all linting features for Python in VSCode and it will show the errors in the code.

This is an optional extension for DJango if you need it.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django